# In cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, drjava

I am following *Prinston*'s course `Algorithms, Part I`. As I came from `.NET` and just started to use `Java`, I have some issue with a piece of `Java` code and I can not find any related information. They provide with a code which I can use for reading a text file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    In in = new In(args[0]);
    int n = in.readInt();
    ...
}
```

Exception thrown:

> In cannot be resolved to a type

What is this `In`? Should I import some package or what should I do?

The whole code and description can be also seen here: http://coursera.cs.princeton.edu/algs4/assignments/collinear.html

Comment: My guess is that In should be Int and new Int(). Ie, the class Integer as opposed to the primitive type.

Comment: Good question. What is this `In`? Syntactically it should be a class. But there is no such class in JDK, so it should be a custom class that obviously unavailable in your project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [algs4](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/), provided by Princeton as well. When it's in the classpath, add

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.In;
```

If that's the only class, you could use [the source of In.java](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/In.java.html).
But I doubt that's allowed on Coursera: when you submit code, it will probably be compiled on the server with algs4.jar in the classpath, so you should really use that one and not your own code.

Comment: I've installed `algs4` and I can use their namespaces like `edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdRandom`, `edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdIn/Out`, but not the class from the question. Let me check the file....

Comment: Hmmmm, I had to use `import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.In;`. They didn't mention it anywhere. Thank you!!!

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: thanks for the comment. I added the import statement to the answer,.

Answer (score 0):

In.java seems to be a class that someone at princeton made, probably for that same course: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/12oop/In.java.

So, yes, you need to import the correct package and you need a jar with that class in your classpath. Search your course documentation for more hints.